# Matching the string with the given 2d char array

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

You are given a matrix of characters. The matrix has N rows and M columns. Given a string s, you have to tell if it is possible to generate that string from given matrix.
Rules for generating string from matrix are:

You have to pick first character of string from row 1, second character from row 2 and so on. The N+1 th character of string is to be picked from row 1, that is, you can traverse the rows in a cyclic manner (row 1 comes after row N).
If an occurrence of a character is picked from a row, you cannot pick the same occurrence again from that row.
You have to print Yes if given string can be generated from matrix using the given rules, else print No.

Input Format:

First line consists of T, denoting the number of test cases.
Each test case consists of:
First line consists of two integers N and M, denoting the matrix dimensions.
Following N lines consist of M characters each.
Last line consists of a string s.

Output Format:
For each test case, print "Yes" if string can be generated else print "No". Answer for each test case should come in a new line.

SAMPLE INPUT 
1
3 3
aba
xyz
bdr
axbaydb

SAMPLE OUTPUT 
Yes

We pick "a" from row 1. Now, we can only pick one more "a" from row 1 as one "a" is already used.
Similarly, "x" from row 2, "b" from row 3.
Now, we again go back to row 1.
We pick "a" from row 1, "y" from row 2 and so on.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int testcase, row, col, x = 0, i = 0;
bool flag = true;
string word;
cin >> testcase; //number of testcases
for (int i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
{
    cin >> row;  //number of rows
    cin >> col;  //number of columns

    char** arr = (char**)malloc(row * sizeof(char *)); //allocating memory for arr pointer to pointer based on the number of rows

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (char*)malloc(col * sizeof(char)); //allocating memory for arr pointer 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    cin>>word;
    while (x < word.length()) // looping through the given string until it reaches the end of the string
    {
        while (i <= row) // looping through the rows of the 2darray
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) //looping through each element in 1d array
            {
                if (i == row) //to ensure that after the last row it goes back again to the first row and starts iterating from the first row
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
                if (word[x] == arr[i][j]) // if character from the string matches the element in the 1st row of 2d array, we will go to the next character of the string and also go to the next row for searching the character in that row.
                {
                    x++;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = false; // if the value is not found, we will set the flag to false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (flag == false)
    {
        cout << "No"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Yes"<<endl;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

The following code is not working as expected

```
1
5 8
wxyqkbtk
xpbzexmh
ffkgmqnj
lfyrrwsn
vqfftarq
tswsgdzlpfxithvahmrffgax
```

Comment: Please add comments to your code showing what you expect will happen at each branch (for statements, exit conditions and while statements and exit conditions.).  Do you have access to a debugger?

Comment: In other words, please use the rubber duck method. You are asking the SO community to be your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).  We are pretty dumb rubber ducks.  Please explain (through comments) your algorithm and each line of code as if talknig to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).  This will help you to become a better programmer, and it will help us help you.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that. I will update it now.

Comment: You're not breaking out of the column loop as soon as a match is found, which means you don't start looking for a match from the start each time you raise the row number. Also you should probably stop looking once you hit a false and just return no.

Comment: The expected output of that test case should be "no" because `s` (the second char of the test case string) is not within the second row of letters, `xpbzexmh`, right?

Comment: Can you also suggest on how to reduce time complexity

Comment: Excellent updates to the comments in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you can't just use vector and string classes to your advantage instead of all this manual malloc'ing and parsing char by char?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int testcase, row, col;
    cin >> testcase;
    for (int i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
    {
        vector<string> rows;
        string word;
        bool allFound = true;
        int rowIndex = 0;

        cin >> row;
        cin >> col;  // you can ignore this value since we read each row as a string

        // read each row and append to the "rows" vector
        for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
        {
            string line;
            cin >> line;
            rows.push_back(line);
        }

        // read the test case word    
        cin >> word;

        // for each letter in word, test to see if that same letter
        // exists on the expected row of input
        for (char c : word)
        {
            string& currentRow = rows[rowIndex];
            if (currentRow.find(c) == string::npos)
            {
                allFound = false;
                break;
            }
            rowIndex = (rowIndex + 1) % row;
        }
        cout << (allFound ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```